# Printing a .ZPL file to a zebra printer in vb.net. Visual Studio 2015 version

Tags: vb.net, printing, visual-studio-2015, zpl, zpl-ii

I already have the raw ZPL file ready to go, I just don't know how to set the printer I want to send it to and then send it. How would I do this?

Note:  I have a batch script on my computer that I default all ZPL files to, which is a shell script that sends the file to the thermal printer on my computer.  I want to get away from that and have all the commands within my application so I don't have to use an external script like that.

This is the code I have now that when ran it auto opens with my batch script:

```
 Sub SaveLabel(ByRef labelFileName As String, ByRef labelBuffer() As Byte)
        ' Save label buffer to file
        Dim myPrinter As New PrinterSettings
        Dim LabelFile As FileStream = New FileStream(labelFileName, FileMode.Create)
        LabelFile.Write(labelBuffer, 0, labelBuffer.Length)
        LabelFile.Close()
        ' Display label
        DisplayLabel(labelFileName)
    End Sub

    Sub DisplayLabel(ByRef labelFileName As String)
        Dim info As System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo = New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(labelFileName)
        info.UseShellExecute = True
        info.Verb = "open"
        info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        info.CreateNoWindow = True
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(info)
    End Sub
```

And this is my batch script:

```
copy %1 \\%ComputerName%\Zebra
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replicate the exact functionality of the batch file in VB.net:

```
Dim filename As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(labelFileName)
System.IO.File.Copy(
                labelFileName,
                Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("\\%ComputerName%\Zebra\" & filename))
```

This copies the file using the method provided by the `System.IO` namespace. It also expands the `%COMPUTERNAME%` environment variable. This replaces all the code in the `DisplayFile` subroutine.

Comment: I was searching all over to try to replicate it in the application, guess i didn't look hard enough.  Thank you sir, you've put an end to my 4 hour despair.